# Recursively List last modified files NIO

Tags: java, search, nio

I am using the below piece of code to list all files in a root folder. (My root directory contains many folders and sub folders.)

```
  Path startPath = Paths.get("D:\\users\\Desktop\\myRootDir");
  Files.walkFileTree(startPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
                 System.out.println(file);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException e) {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
```

is there any way to list out only last modified files and is there any way to search through the content of the file as well in java NIO?

Note: By last modified file I mean the file which created recently in one folder.

**UPDATE**

```
           @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
                System.out.println(dir.getFileName());
                if(dir.getFileName().equals("processes"))
                    return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
                else
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException e) {
            FileInfo mostRecentFile = mostRecentFilesByDir.remove(dir);
            if (mostRecentFile != null) {
              //  System.out.println(mostRecentFile.path);
            }

            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
```

The above code still returns the files from processes directory, Am i doing any mistake here?

Comment: Define _last modified files_.

Comment: How recently? You're given the file attributes, check them.

Comment: What do you mean by "search through the content of each file"?  Do you want to assume every file is a text file and search it for a particular string?

Comment: yes, same like text file @VGR

Comment: Do you want to find the most recently created matching file, or the most recently created file if and only if it matches?

Comment: only recently created matching file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the most recently created file in each directory which contains specific text.  You can do this by tracking each directory's most recent file in a Map, and by passing each file to a Scanner:

```
String textToSearchFor = "important";
final Pattern searchPattern =
    Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(textToSearchFor));

Path startPath = Paths.get("D:\\users\\Desktop\\myRootDir");
Files.walkFileTree(startPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

    class FileInfo {
        final FileTime time;
        final Path path;

        FileInfo(Path path, FileTime time) {
            this.path = path;
            this.time = time;
        }
    }

    private final Map<Path, FileInfo> mostRecentFilesByDir =
        new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException e) {

        FileInfo mostRecentFile = mostRecentFilesByDir.remove(dir);
        if (mostRecentFile != null) {
            System.out.println(mostRecentFile.path);
        }

        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                                     BasicFileAttributes attrs)
    throws IOException {

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            if (scanner.findWithinHorizon(searchPattern, 0) == null) {
                // Text not found.
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        }

        FileTime time = attrs.creationTime();
        Path dir = file.getParent();
        FileInfo info = mostRecentFilesByDir.get(dir);
        if (info == null || time.compareTo(info.time) > 0) {
            mostRecentFilesByDir.put(dir, new FileInfo(file, time));
        }

        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException e) {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

Comment: @VGS, How to exclude files and directories with certain name from search?

Comment: To skip a directory, check its name, and if you want to skip it, return SKIP_SUBTREE from the preVisitDirectory method.  To skip a file, you can simply check its name in the visitFile method and avoid adding it if the name isn't what you want.

Comment: I updated my question, as shown there, i am using that code, but still my program is returning/reading from processes directory, is anything wrong there?

Comment: The [getFileName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--) method of Path returns another Path object, so `dir.getFileName().equals("processes")` will always be false.  A Path object is never equal to a String object.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

1. When doing preVisitDirectory, then do have Path lastModified where keep a Path which is the last modified in this directory (on visitFile check file for last modified time if it is later than the one of the file referenced by lastModified then do lastModified = "that file";
2. When doing postVisitDirectory add lastModified to a `List<Path>`.
   That way you will build a list of lastModified files across directories. If you need to store the n lastModified files, then do the same but changing lastModified to `List<Path>.`

Comment: Thanks, if i want to search through all those last modified files, is it good to first finding out list of last modified files and then performing a search in those files?  you said " do have Path lastModified " you mean where?

Comment: The algo sounds simpler than it is. I would store Path lastModified for each Path (i.e. folder visited). That lastModified would be declared after 
Path startPath = Paths.get("D:\\users\\Desktop\\myRootDir"); final 
Map<Path, Path> lastModified = new LinkedHashMap<>();//key Path is for the directory where the last modified resides, value Path is for the Path file that has the latest modification time.
If u need n last modified files for each directory, then use final Map<Path, List<Path>> lastModified = new LinkedHashMap<>();
lastModified should be final, to be accessible from anonymous class.

Comment: It could be made to run another thread that starts searching in those files, that are from the _completely_ visited directories. But this approach would require a class that extends Path and has a boolean field visitedDirectory.

Comment: The files to be searched in should be selected from the directories, that have visitedDirectory == true.